# group parent of parent in mysql

Tags: mysql

my table structur

```
CREATE TABLE test_lot
(
    id            int AUTO_INCREMENT
        PRIMARY KEY,
    lot_no        varchar(10) NULL,
    weight        float       NULL,
    parant_lot_no varchar(10) NULL
);
```

the table values

```
id  lot_no  weight  parant_lot_no
1   p-1-0   0   
2   p-2-0   10  
3   p-1-1   5   p-1-0
4   p-1-2   5   p-1-0
5   p-2-1   5   p-2-0
6   p-2-2   0   p-2-0
7   p-2-3   3   p-2-2
8   p-2-4   2   p-2-2
```

I purchase two products  and its lot_no p-1-0 & p-2-0 with the weight of 10 & 20 its initial buy so there is no parant_lot_no.

```
after that i divided(repack) the p-1-0 into two pack p-1-1 its weight is 5 and p-1-2 is 5 so the parent lot is zero

    similerly i split 
        p-2-0(weight 20) into p-2-1 in to 5
        p-2-0(weight 20) into p-2-2 in to 5
    
     so the parent lot p-2-0 have remaining of 10 weight
    
    forther i split p-2-2 into two
    
    p-2-3 -> 3
    p-2-4 -> 2  so the lot p-2-2 gos to zero weight
    
    expected result is if i give the parent id its give the total weight of that
    
    eg
    p-1-0 return 10
    p-2-0 return 20
    p-2-2 return 5
```

Comment: What is MySQL version? What is lots divide maximal depth?

Comment: I wonder if this question could be any more confusing

Comment: MySQL version : 10.4.8-MariaDB. and no limitation for depth